# Javascript - Save image to internal storage

Tags: javascript

I am downloading a image from server as blob and then converting it into url and displaying the image.

```js
var nImageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
nImageRequest.open("POST", "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/server/api/download_image.php", true);

nImageRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
nImageRequest.responseType = 'blob';

nImageRequest.onreadystatechange = function(oEvent) {

  if (nImageRequest.readyState == 4) {
    if (nImageRequest.status == 200) {

      var image = new Image();
      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      image.src = url.createObjectURL(nImageRequest.response);
      document.body.appendChild(image);

      // window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT , 1024*1024, SaveDatFileBro);
    }
  }
};

nImageRequest.send(imageFilename);
```

Now, I want to store it in **internal storage of user's phone**. How to do that using `javascript`

Comment: what about, localstorage?

Comment: I already did it, but I want my user to save the image in his phone either in internal storage or sd card.

Comment: https://github.com/yrezgui/FileSaver.js

Comment: Ahh ok! If you are using phonegap, this could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371664/how-to-create-file-in-sdcard-using-phonegap

Comment: @Kaiido I saw that solution. Will it work for android phone??

Comment: @Jeremy Using phonegap or cordova now will not be feasible. Is there any other way to save the image to internal storage.

Comment: What are you using here, is it a webapp or phoneapp?

Comment: According to their [browser support](https://github.com/yrezgui/FileSaver.js#supported-browsers) it fully supports Chrome for Android and Safari without filename

Comment: @jeremy I am using webview in Application.

Comment: @kaiido Yeah i tested it in chrome and it works fine but when I run it in my phone, nothing downloads.

Comment: I did found something, but I am not sure if this will be a good solution to my current problem. The solution is to pass the image as blob to java activity in my app and then from there save it to internal storage. Any advice is appreciated.